# Google Classroom API returns student profile JSON having no email address

Tags: google-classroom

Getting student JSON from Google that doesn't contain any email address and user's name contains the value "Unknown User".

```
 {
     "courseId":"1234",
     "profile":{//No email address
             "id":"openId",
             "name":{"fullName":"Unknown user"},//Why "Unknown user"
             "photoUrl":"correct_url"
     },
     "userId":"openId"
}
```

We can not access teacher's Google Classroom account so we are trying to reproduce the issue with the test account. It's happening for only few users, working fine for all others.

We are using Google Classroom's Java API.

Example code that we are using:

```
Classroom service = getGoogleClassRoomService(accessToken);
if(service != null) {
    ListStudentsResponse studentsResponse = service.courses().students().list(courseId).execute();
    List<Student> students = studentsResponse.getStudents();
    if(students != null) {
        for (Student student : students) {
            if (student.getProfile().getEmailAddress() != null) {
                //Processing student data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Need to know the scenario when email address can be null for student, technically it should not be null.

Example student profile JSON reference: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/userProfiles#resource-userprofile

Scopes requested while authenticating the user:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly

Comment: I know it is quite old question but Had You found any solution ?

Comment: No solution, just ignored such data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the user have been deleted? In some circumstances the API will return a "user" with "Unknown user" as the name (and no email address) if the user has been deleted.

Comment: I see OP has accepted this, but I'm having the same problem, and these are not deleted users. If I find a solution I'll reference it here.

Answer (score 4):

In order to have email addresses returned you need to request the special `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails` OAuth scope.

Comment: Already doing this, updated the question. As I have already mentioned that the code is working fine for all other users so it shouldn't be scope issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Need to know the scenario when email address can be null for student, technically it should not be null.

This happens when the G-Suite admin deletes the account of students. This will only delete the user account, it doesn't remove the user from Google classrooms. Which will leave a ghost user in those classrooms where this user was a part of.

Fortunately, G-Suite allows to recover deleted users within 20 days. If the admin recovers such users, you'll be able to see the students in their respective classrooms and can remove them gracefully from each classrooms.

I'm not sure how to resolve this if 20 days have passed after User deletion.